# What causes elusive: NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint()?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jndi

Many people have asked for help with this error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/xnio/OptionMap;)Lorg/jboss/remoting3/Endpoint;]

at
org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:51)

at
org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:152)

at
javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)

...
```

But no request I can find ever provides a conclusive answer. Just suggestions to tinker with jars.

I believe that’s because there’s an inconsistency in the structure of Jboss interfaces. Can anyone confirm or correct that?

Here’s my code that throws the above error:

```
final private Properties env = new Properties() {
  {put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");  
   put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:9990");
   put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "myID");  
   put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "myPassword");
   put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);  
  }
};
/****************************************************
 * myID & myPassword open the Admin GUI for wildfly *
 * on localhost:9990                                *
 ****************************************************/

Context ctx = new InitialContext(this.env);
```

To determine the required jars I removed all jars from the Build path. 
Then I ran my program till all ClassNotFoundException were gone.

First Error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory]
```

Added jboss-remote-naming-1.0.7.final.jar to class path

Second Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/jboss/logging/Logger
```

Added jboss-logging.jar

Third Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/xnio/Options
```

Added xnio-api-3.0.7.ga.jar

Fourth Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/jboss/remoting3/spi/ConnectionProviderFactory
```

Added jboss-remoting-3.jar

Fifth Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/jboss/ejb/client/EJBClientContextIdentifier
```

Added jboss-ejb-client-1.0.19.final.jar

FINAL AND FATAL ERROR 
(Note: All NoClassDefFoundError have been cleared)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/xnio/OptionMap;)Lorg/jboss/remoting3/Endpoint;]
```

Using Eclipse’s Project Explorer I verified:

a. jboss-remoting3.jar has the org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting Class.

b. That Remoting Class has this Method:

public Endpoint createEndpoint (String, Executor, OptionMap)

Note it calls for 3 parameters.

BUT the FINAL FATAL ERROR above calls for

public Endpoint createEndpoint (String, OptionMap)

Note: it calls for 2 parameters. Hence the NoSuchMethodError.

Looking at the top lines in the stack trace, I guess
org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext() is trying to call org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint() using 2 parameters, but org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting only defines createEndpoint() with a 3-paramater signature.

Is that supposed to even be possible? 
A jar that says it has the org.jboss.remoting3 package whose Remoting class has a single createEndpoint() method with a 3-parameter signature, and another jar that says it has the org.jboss.remoting3 package whose Remoting class has another createEndpoint() method with a 2-parameter signature?

HELP!

I mean do I need to look through every org.jboss.remoting3 package to find one whose Remoting class has a 2 parameter createEnpoint() method?

Or am I missing something important.

I mean this does explain how many questions have been posted about this error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/xnio/OptionMap;)Lorg/jboss/remoting3/Endpoint;]
```

And explain why there is never a conclusive explanation or solution other than fiddling with jars and build path.

I mean getting an InitialContext from WildFly running on the same PC as the Java program should be a trivial process.  But it hasn’t been. Maybe it's because of inconsistencies in the API.

Comment: Usually this sort of thing is caused by a versioning problem. You're calling a method in version 1 but compiling against version 2 of the library. Or in this case, you're calling code in jboss-ejb-client-1.0.19.final.jar which is expecting a 2010 version of jboss-remoting-3.jar and you're using a 2017 version of jboss-remoting-3.jar (or something). Usually it's best to use a JBoss-provided BOM or similar, to avoid this sort of problem. [Here are some BOMs](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-boms), maybe one will suit your needs?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Christoph Böhme:

**jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar** has an org.jboss.remeoting package with a Remoting class that has createEndpoint() with a 0, 2 and 3 parameter signature.

Replacing **jboss-remoting-4.0.7.Final.jar** with the above jar was all it required to clear the NoSuchMethodError.

Hope that helps others.